# Can I set a default dashboard layout for all users?

Tags: admin, dashboard, author

I'm creating a multi-author blog, and have recently added the "Dashboard Notepads" plugin. This allows me to add 1 to 3 dashboard widgets which I can write custom notes in, like news or notices. Is there a way I can set that widget to appear at the top by default? 
I had a look but could only find a plugin which works up to 2.8. Using version 3.0.4.
I would much rather do this without the need to change code, although I would consider it as a last resort option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi **@Relequestual:**

I think what you want is here:

- [**Dashboard Widgets API / Advanced: Forcing your widget to the top**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API#Advanced%3a_Forcing_your_widget_to_the_top)

It doesn't require you to change code per se, just to add the code like shown in the WordPress Codex to your theme's  `functions.php` file which is a standard way to customize and/or extend WordPress:

To find out the values you need use, just add a `print_r($wp_meta_boxes);` line then an `exit;` immediately below the `global $wp_meta_boxes;` line like this:

```
global $wp_meta_boxes;
print_r($wp_meta_boxes);
exit;  // Stop execution here so you can see it.
```

You may need to actually view source to make sense of it all.

-Mike

Comment: Fantastic. I believe this is exactly what I was after. I did have a look in the wordpress codex, but didn't figure to check the dashboard widget API.

Comment: @Relequestual - Glad I could help! :)